# How to invisible the textview on the listview by onclick based on the textview position

Tags: android, android-listview, textview, onclick, hide

I have a list view in the holder, I want to hide the holder.start textview when I click on the same textview and visible the holder.stop textview, if I do the following code, it hides the last list view position please help to do this

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView =setViewIdToHolder(convertView,parent,position);
    }
    //populate vive method
    populateView(position, convertView);
    BookedUserObject booked = this.getItem(position);
    Animation animation = null;
    animation = new ScaleAnimation(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    animation.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
    animation.setDuration(600);
    convertView.startAnimation(animation);
    return convertView;
}
//link here
private void populateView(int position, View convertView) {
    final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    BookedUserObject booked_obj = this.getItem(position);
    holder.name.setText(booked_obj.getName());
    holder.source.setText(booked_obj.getSource());
    holder.destination.setText(booked_obj.getDestination());
    holder.start.setTag(position);
    holder.stop.setTag(position);
}

private View setViewIdToHolder(View rowView, ViewGroup parent,int position) {
    rowView = ((Activity) this.getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.match_booked_user_list, parent, false);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    holder.source = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.source);
    holder.destination = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.destination);
    holder.start = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.start);
    holder.stop = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.stop);

   holder.start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {`enter code here`
            final int position = (Integer) view.getTag();
            start(position);
    //IF I DO THIS THIS HIDES THE LAST LISTVIEW POSITION TEXTVIEW
           holder.start.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```